# Disable local storage of Sharepoint Workspace documents on a per user basis

Tags: workspace

This should be fairly simple. I want to use Sharepoint Workspaces to share documents. Most clients will be using a secured network to connect. I'm not worried about them. I am worried about other clients (contractors, vendors, etc) that are not on a secured network. I would like to lump everyone who isn't using a secured network into a group, and somehow prevent them from downloading the documents onto their computers, in case something happens.

Is there any way to prevent certain users from having a local copy of a file on their machine, yet still edit the documents in-browser only?

Answer (score 1):

You could configure [Information Rights Management](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms458245%28v=office.14%29) and then enable it on the document libraries you wish to protect. SharePoint Workspace will honor those IRM settings.

[Securing SharePoint documents that you take offline](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sharepoint_workspace_development_team/securing-sharepoint-documents-that-you-take-offline)